# Crystal Reports Version 10

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

A Colleague of mine has inherited an old VB.Net web application that uses Crystal reports 10.

However, we're unable to find the developer version of this module and it won't build with Crystal Reports 2010.

Can anyone recall which version of Visual Studio came with Crystal Reports developer edition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be Visual Studio .NET 2003